# Simplifying the division of integrals

Tags: integration

Is there a way to simplify this division of integrals, or at least find a bound for it, without writing it in terms of CDF of Beta?

I tried to use the idea [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634073/simplifying-division-of-integrals) but didn't have much luck.

$$\frac{\int_l^u  x^a (1-x)^{b-1} \;dx}{\int_l^u x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \; dx}$$

Comment: Are ther any restrictions for $l$ and $u$? Because if $l=0$ and $u=1$ you could rewrite this fraction using Beta or Gamma functions. Or, without these conditions, maybe in terms of the incomplete Beta function. I have asked similiar question by myself and I would be interested in an answer too.

Comment: @mrtaurho  $l >0$  and  $u < 1$.

Comment: Doesn't the identity $$\int_l^u x^a (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx=\int_l^u x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx-\int_l^u x^{a-1} (1-x)^b \, dx$$, and that the integrals are all positive, imply that the division of the above integrals is bounded between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

I would try it as follows:

$$\int_l^u x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~=~\int_0^u x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~-~\int_0^l x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\int_l^u x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~=~\int_0^u x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~-~\int_0^l x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x$$

With the incomplete Beta function

$$B(x; a,b)~=~ \int_0^x x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x$$

The fraction would become

$$\begin{align}\frac{\int_l^u x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x}{\int_l^u x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x}~&=~\frac{\int_0^u x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~-~\int_0^l x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^u x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x~-~\int_0^l x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm{d}x}\\~&=~\frac{B(u;a+1,b)-B(l;a+1,b)}{B(u;a,b)-B(l;a,b)}\end{align}$$

First of all I am not sure if this is even possible to do so in this way and on the other hand I am not sure if this helps.

I do not know another way without the incomplete Beta function.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this way of derivation(I mentioned in the question without using CDF of beta). I'm interested in another way without using the incomplete beta.

Comment: I just realized it afterwards. I am not familiar with another of simplification but as I already mentioned I would be interested in one too.